# Django: Django-userena csrf 404 error

Tags: python, django, csrf

I have just migrated after having django-registration to Django-userena just because it is more maintained and after setting everything up and I try to make a test account, I am prompted with the following 403 message:

> Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed.
>
> CSRF token missing or incorrect.

Any ideas on how to fix this or where I can find the files to Django-userena to investigate?
Any help would be nice.

Comment: Have you upgraded your django as well?

Comment: How you are rendering your template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that you have `{% csrf_token %}` inside the `<form></form>` tags, in template where user creation form located.

if you are using virtualenv, files to Django-userena should be in

```
{your environment}/lib/python*/site-packages/userena
```